# Cancel execuction of Observable (RxJava 1)

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have created Observable with subscripiton:

```
private Subscription mSearchSubscription = null;

mSearchSubscription = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    many network requests
}).subscribe(doing sth);
```

When my activity is destroyed I am executing following line:

```
 if (mSearchSubscription != null){
        mSearchSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
```

According to informations found in internet this line should cancel all code execution from this block. But it doesn't :( All network requests inside this block are wrapped Observables with subscribe so when one request is finished next one is executing and so on. As I noticed after unsubscribe is executed and activity is destroyed code inside Observable is still executing.

Is there any better way to stop it? I am using in this project RxJava1

Update:
I have MVC architecture with controller Injected into Activity. By overriding onDestroy from activity I call method in controller to unsubscribe. This is whole code. Every network request inside block fromCallable(()-> ) is like this mWebService.getSth(body parameters).subscribe(doSth) (in interface this return Observable ) . I am not expecting to stop during execution of internal observable, but stop executing this block of code, just like return. This is wrapped because of many requests needed to be executed one by one and return result to activity when everything is ready.

Comment: Where exactly do you unsubscribe the `Observable`? If you're creating it in the `Activity`, then you should unsubscribe it in `onPause()` method. In case of using it somewhere else (e.g. in `Service`), then you should unsubscribe it in other method with respect to the lifecycle of the particular component. There could be also problem, with the implementation of the `Observable`, but we cannot see it in your post. It could be implemented in a wrong way and there could be a memory leak, which causes problem encountered by you.

Comment: Please provide the internals of that `fromCallable` call. Also you mentioned "wrapped Observables with subscribe" inside it which is definitely wrong because those are disconnected from the outer `subscribe` call.

Comment: I have MVC architecture with controller Injected into Activity. By overriding onDestroy from activity I call method in controller to unsubscribe. This is whole code. Every network request inside block fromCallable(()-> ) is like this mWebService.getSth(body parameters).subscribe(doSth)  (in interface this return Observable<sth> ) .  I am not expecting to stop during execution of internal observable, but stop executing this block of code, just like return. This is wrapped because of many requests needed to be executed one by one and return result to activity when everything is ready.

Comment: @masztalski please update **the question** instead of writing code in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much details on how and why you do that, so my best guess-suggestion is to use `create`:

```java
Observable.create(emitter -> {
    CompositeSubscription resources = new CompositeSubscription();
    emitter.setSubscription(resources);

    if (resources.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    }

    // add these if you want to cancel the inner sources
    // resources.add(

    mWebService.getFirst(/* params */).subscribe(/* postprocess */);

    // );

    if (resources.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    }
    mWebService.getSecond(/* params */).subscribe(/* postprocess */);

    if (resources.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    }

    mWebService.getThird(/* params */).subscribe(/* postprocess */);

    emitter.onNext(/* the result object*/
    emitter.onComplete();
}, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(/* work with the data */);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Idea of checking if is unsubscrubied before each call seems good solution. I will try it tommorow